# VBA winapi findwindowEx - send text to the same class handler name

Tags: vba, winapi, findwindow

I am writing a VBA to write text in a third party program.
There are 2 window class name with the same name "Edit" under "subwin" - "wxWindowNR".

I am able to send message to the first "Edit" but not the second one.

How am i able to send text to the second "Edit?

```
Sub writeTextOnWin()
Dim i As Long
Dim wClass As Object

hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "mkvmerge GUI")

start_doc = ShellExecute(hWnd, "open", "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mmg.exe", "", 0, SW_NORMAL)

If start_doc = 2 Then Exit Sub
If start_doc = 3 Then Exit Sub

Do
DoEvents
hwindow2 = FindWindow(vbNullString, "mkvmerge GUI v7.7.0 ('Six Voices') 64bit")
Loop Until hwindow2 > 0


mainWin = FindWindowEx(hwindow2, 0&, "wxWindowNR", vbNullString)
subWin = FindWindowEx(subWin, 0&, "wxWindowNR", vbNullString)

editWin = FindWindowEx(subWin, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
editWin2 = FindWindowEx(subWin, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)

Call SendMessageByString(editWin, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "hello")
Call SendMessageByString(editWin2, WM_SETTEXT, 1, "hello again")

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`FindWindowEx` is the wrong tool for the job here. Both of the windows that you look for have the same class name, and since the window text is not predictable, `FindWindowEx` is not appropriate.

Instead you need to iterate over the children of `subWin` looking for the two edit windows. There are two obvious ways to do that:

1. Call [`EnumChildWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx) to enumerate all of the children of `subWin`. You will need to provide a callback function for this. This is perfectly possible in VBA but requires more complexity than your current code.
2. Use [`GetWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx) to walk over the children of `subWin`. Pass `GW_CHILD` on the first call to get the first child. Then, call again passing the latest child and `GW_HWNDNEXT`. Keep calling `GetWindow` until you've found your windows.